# PDF doesn't generate UTF-8 characters REACT

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jspdf

Basically I'm creating a website that lets user to download a pdf file that includes all the information needed. The problem I've encountered is that UTF-8 characters are not being shown, even though the font has been changed. I have ttf file the same file but converted as js file and the main generator file. The name of ttf file is Titillium-Regular.ttf. The name of Javascript file is - Titillium-Regular-normal.js.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import WHButton from '../../redesign/components/WHButton';
import Arial from './Titillium-Regular.ttf'; //don't mind this 


class DefectsPDFGenerator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generatePDF = this.generatePDF.bind(this);
  }

  addImageWithPageBreak(pdf, image, x, y, width, height) {
    const maxY = pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 10;
    if (y + height > maxY) {
      pdf.addPage();
      y = 10;
    }
    let newY = y + height + 6;
    const commentLines = pdf.splitTextToSize(image.comment, width);
    pdf.addImage(image.source, 'PNG', x, y, width, height);
    commentLines.forEach((line, index) => {
      pdf.text(line, x, y + height + 7 + (index * 7));
      newY = y + height + 7 + index * 7 + 6;
    });
    return newY;
  }

  // loadFontFile = async () => {
  //   try {
  //     const response = await fetch(Arial);
  //     const fontBinaryArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
  //     const fontBinaryString = new Uint8Array(fontBinaryArrayBuffer).reduce(
  //       (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
  //       ''
  //     );

  //     this.generatePDF(fontBinaryString);
  //   } catch (error) {
  //     console.error('Error loading font file:', error);
  //   }
  // };

  generatePDF() {
    const { defects } = this.props;

    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    
    // pdf.setFont(`courier`)
    // console.log(pdf.getFontList());
    pdf.setFont('Titillium-Regular', 'normal')


    let yPosition = 20;
    pdf.text(`Objekts: ${defects.object.name}`, 10, yPosition);
    pdf.text(`Tips: ${defects.type.name}`, 10, yPosition + 10);
    pdf.text(`Status: ${defects.defectstatus}`, 10, yPosition + 20);
    pdf.text(`Pieteicejs: ${defects.user.name}`, 10, yPosition + 30);
    pdf.text(`Komentars: ${defects.comment}`, 10, yPosition + 40);
    pdf.text(`Pieteikuma datums: ${defects.created}`, 10, yPosition + 50);

    let yImagePosition = yPosition + 60;

    defects.images.forEach((image) => {
      const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;
      const imageWidth = 155;
      const xPosition = (pageWidth - imageWidth) / 2;

      // pdf.addFileToVFS('Titillium-Regular.ttf', fontBinaryString);
      // pdf.addFont('Titillium-Regular.ttf', 'Titillium-Regular', 'normal');
      // pdf.setFont('Titillium-Regular');

      yImagePosition = this.addImageWithPageBreak(
        pdf,
        image,
        xPosition,
        yImagePosition,
        imageWidth,
        85
      );
    });

    pdf.save('defects.pdf');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table id="defects-table"></table>
        <WHButton
          onClick={this.generatePDF}  
          text="Lejupielādēt"
          className="mobile-center"
          icon="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"
          outline
          small
          right
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DefectsPDFGenerator;
```

Javascript file

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
var font = ...... (BASE64 string) 
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('Titillium-Regular.ttf', font);
this.addFont('Titillium-Regular.ttf', 'Titillium-Regular', 'normal');
};
jsPDF.API.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
```

Basically I'm creating a website that lets user to download a pdf file that includes all the information needed. The problem I've encountered is that UTF-8 characters are not being shown, even though the font has been changed. I have tried for the whole day and it just doesnt work as it should. Dont know where the issue might be